# pandas groupBy date then filter date and string into new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm struggling here, I'm looking to take the following data, group by date, then check the rows within the group to determine whether or not the group has any location data associated with it, if yes, extract it.

My data sample:

```
id,dates,text,place
1,2017-01-26 01:06:47,text,"Place(country_code='US', full_name='Manhattan, NY', place_type='city', name='Manhattan', contained_within=[], _api=<tweepy.api.API object at 0x10336f320>, attributes={}, country='United States', bounding_box=BoundingBox(type='Polygon', coordinates=[[[-74, 40], [-73, 40], [-73, 40], [-74, 40]]], _api=<tweepy.api.API object at 0x10336f320>))"
2,2017-01-26 01:05:51,text,"Place(country_code='US', full_name='Manhattan, NY', place_type='city', name='Manhattan', contained_within=[], _api=<tweepy.api.API object at 0x10336f320>, attributes={}, country='United States', bounding_box=BoundingBox(type='Polygon', coordinates=[[[-74, 40], [-73, 40], [-73, 40], [-74, 40]]], _api=<tweepy.api.API object at 0x10336f320>))"
4,2017-01-23 01:38:29,text,
5,2017-01-23 01:36:53,text,
```

I begin by loading the csv and grouping the dates

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
df1 = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df = df1[['dates','place']]
df['dates']=pd.to_datetime(df['dates'],format='%Y-%m-%d')
df.index=df['dates']

grp = pd.groupby(df,by=[df.index.year,df.index.month,df.index.day])
for date,group in grp:
    print(date)
    print(group)
```

This will yield a dataframe that looks like this:

```
(2017, 1, 26)
                                  dates  \
dates
2017-01-26 01:06:47 2017-01-26 01:06:47
2017-01-26 01:05:51 2017-01-26 01:05:51

                                                                 place
dates
2017-01-26 01:06:47  Place(country_code='US', full_name='Manhattan,...
2017-01-26 01:05:51                                                NaN
```

Here is where I run into problems with filtering/conditionals, my goal is to have a dataframe that I can save to a csv that looks like this:

```
date, item_count, has_location, location
2017-01-26, 2, yes, Manhattan
2017-01-23, 2, no, na
```

What is the best way to proceed? Thanks

Comment: I am not sure, but it seems output is different with input - there is problematic row with `id=3`. I try omit it with my solution, please check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use:

[`extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) `name` with column `place` first and then `groupby` by [`dt.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.date.html) (if `dtype` of column `dates` is `datetime`, [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) can be removed) and aggregate by `size` some of columns e.g. `id` and by `first` column `place`. Last [`insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) new column created by [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
print (df)
   id                dates  text  \
0   1  2017-01-26 01:06:47  text   
1   2  2017-01-26 01:05:51  text   
2   4  2017-01-23 01:38:29  text   
3   5  2017-01-23 01:36:53  text   

                                               place  
0  Place(country_code='US', full_name='Manhattan,...  
1  Place(country_code='US', full_name='Manhattan,...  
2                                                NaN  
3                                                NaN  

df.place = df.place.str.extract(", name='(.*)', contained_within", expand=True)
print (df)
   id                dates  text      place
0   1  2017-01-26 01:06:47  text  Manhattan
1   2  2017-01-26 01:05:51  text  Manhattan
2   4  2017-01-23 01:38:29  text        NaN
3   5  2017-01-23 01:36:53  text        NaN

df1 = df.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df.dates).dt.date).agg({'id':'size', 'place':'first'})
df1.columns = ['item_count','location']
df1.insert(1, 'has_location', np.where(df1.location.isnull(), 'no', 'yes'))
print (df1)
            item_count has_location   location
dates                                         
2017-01-23           2           no        NaN
2017-01-26           2          yes  Manhattan
```

Comment: to deal with id=3, use this `agg({'size', 'first', lambda x: x.isnull().any()})` to determine has_location

Comment: @Boud - thank you, but then count is `3` not `2` (maybe typo), I dont know if understand well it.

Comment: We have to recognize OP did a great job for bringing something reproductible but the final question is unclear indeed.

Comment: @jezrael sorry for any confusion, how can i update my question to make it more clear for readers?

Comment: @snake_pliskin - I think you need remove only row with `index=3`, then output is by input.

Comment: @jezrael i removed row 3, thanks much for assisting!

Comment: @snake_pliskin - but I have question - is this answer what need? Because I aggreagte by date and then extract `location` from first row. Is possible for one date is multiple `location`? What if first location is `NaN` and then second is `Manhattan` and third is `Manhattan1` ? Is it possible?

Comment: @jezrael thanks for helping, yes that is possible, the group may have the location mixed in different rows, so it shouldn't be limited to just the first or last row

if 
row 1 = NaN
row 2 = Manhattan
row 3 = Manhattan
row 4 = NaN

the result should just say "Manhattan"

Comment: @snake_pliskin - Thank you for accepting. If find some problem with my solution, the best is working with more rows of your data. Please contact me with my email in my profile and add csv (if not confidental data).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134224/discussion-between-snake-pliskin-and-jezrael).